# remove jquery css on click

Tags: jquery, css

I've got an image on my site, and everytime I click on that, it slides open a box with 4 links.
The image starts at 0.6 opacity, and when you click on it to open the box, gets opacity 1.
However I would like that when you close the box, the opacity goes back to 0.6.

My code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();
    jQuery(".moduletable span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({
            opacity: '1'
        });         
        $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(300);
        $this.next("div").slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Hope you can help me out.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function) on your `fadeOut()` to set the opacity back to 0.6 after the animation has completed:

```
$('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(300, function() { 
    $this.css({opacity:'0.6'});
});
```

Comment: +1, although the method signature is `fadeout(duration, callback)`

Comment: Hey James,

Thanks alot for your assistance. I've tried adding that callback function to my fadeout, but now it seems like it skips the opacity change on the first click, as it remains on 0.6 opacity.

Comment: @user2882079 you have to remember that 300ms is a very short time (1/3 of a second). If you increase this to say 3000 (3 seconds) you'll notice the transition a bit easier. If you want to delay the opacity change, however, you can always use `setTimeout`. Wrap the `$this.css(...)` above in `setTimeout(function() { $this.css(...) },  1000)` - the `1000` here is 1000ms (1 second).

Comment: Hey James. Think you misunderstood me. After I've added the code, the opacity never changes to 1 when I click on the image, like it did before.

Comment: The code that I've supplied doesn't change any of your existing code other than your `fadeOut` function. Are any JavaScript errors being thrown?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a javascript error, but it's complaining about missing http://localhost/jquery-2.0.3.min.map.

Comment: @user2882079 do you still have `$this.css({opacity:'1'})` in your code? jQuery's `.map` file is used for debugging and wouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Yeah, the code I've got now is this:
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

    jQuery(".moduletable span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
      $this.css({
       opacity: '1'
       });
     $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(1200, function() {
     $this.css({opacity:'0.6'});<br />
     });<br />
     $this.next("div").slideToggle(300);
     
      
    });
   });
  </script>